# How to use panic=abort with external dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

For single crate projects, adding these lines to `Cargo.toml` works as expected.

```
[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

Then build the project:

```
cargo build --release
```

---

However, on a project which has indirectly used dependencies, I'm getting an error.

```
    Compiling c_vec v1.0.12
error: the linked panic runtime `panic_unwind` is not compiled with this crate's panic strategy `abort`

error: aborting due to previous error

Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: Could not compile `c_vec`.
```

The `c_vec` crate is an indirectly used dependency.

How to use `panic=abort` on a multi-crate project without conflicts?

---

Details incase they matter:

- Rustc 1.12.0
- Library with issue: [lodepng-rust](https://github.com/pornel/lodepng-rust)
- Linux, 64bit

Comment: What's your rust version? On the current nightly I can't even get c_vec to build to help test this out.

Comment: @Jsor, added details

Comment: thanks, and what exactly are you doing to trigger the panic?

Comment: @Jsor, nothing, its not even building.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32837 I'm thinking it wasn't actually totally fixed. I'm trying to add a comment, but Github's servers are dying right now.

Comment: Sorry, this issue https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2738

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's because `c_vec` specifies `dylib` as one of its library types.

I found this as an issue on Github here: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2738

> ah unfortunately that's a bad error message but it's
> because of crate-type = ["dylib", "rlib"] in the c_vec crate. This
> causes Cargo to pass -C prefer-dynamic which links to the dylib that
> we ship which is compiled against panic_unwind, meaning the abort mode
> is indeed invalid (this error is coming from the compiler).
>
> The fix here would be to remove "dylib" from the c_vec crate.

Of course, you'd have to fork your own `lodepng` and `c_vec` to take care of this.

Comment: I don't remember the technique off-hand, but I remember reading that Cargo supports local dependency overlays, so I'd assume you only need to fork `c_vec` if that's the only one specifying `dylib`.